# GLSurfaceView not displayed after emulator-update 12/02/2021

Tags: android-studio, emulation, glsurfaceview

After the last emulator update, the emulator no longer shows the GLSurfaceView. The other views are displayed. Before the update everything was ok and everything is displayed on the physical device too.
Is it possible to undo the update or does anyone know how to solve the problem.
I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Solved: I added this to my onSurfaceCreated method:
 gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);
 gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

Comment: Remember, You can answer your own question. But remember to add some  code examples of what you were trying to achieve and where you got stuck